# input tag and form tag within php

Tags: php, mysql

Okay so guys, I'm new to PHP. I'm having problems adding an "Edit" button as fourth element on 4th column(Action) which is a th. I'll need to add an Edit button on each of book titles and bring the user to an Edit page so they can Edit the book information. 
I don't know what to do next. I don't know how to add the button and at the same time pass the edit request through POST. What should I change? How do I embed the html  within php

Btw, I'm using XAMPP and notepad++

Thanks.

```
<?php
include('databaseConnection.php');
?>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/librarySystem.css">
<title> Book List </title>
</head>

<div id="booklist_container">

    <table id="booklist_table">
        <?php

                $select_all_books = "SELECT * FROM booklist";
                $result = mysql_query($select_all_books);

                echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<th>" ."Title". "</th>" ;   
                                echo "<th>" ."Author". "</th>" ;
                                echo "<th>" ."ISBN" . "</th>" ;
                                echo "<th>" ."Action". "</th>";
                echo "</tr>";

                echo  "<form method="POST" action="edit.php">" ;

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        $authorVar = $row['Author'];  
                        $titleVar = $row['Title'];
                        $ISBN = $row['ISBN'];

                        echo "<tr>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $titleVar. "</td>";   
                                        echo "<td>" . $authorVar. "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $ISBN . "</td>";
                                            echo"<input type="button" value="Edit Info">"  ;

                        echo "</tr>"; 
                    } // end of while loop

                echo  "</form>" ;
        ?>

    </table>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: `echo"<input type="button" value="Edit Info">";` using this http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php would have thrown you a syntax parse error.

Comment: @Fred-ii- What did you do that for? He had several problems in addition to his quotation errors and I just spent 10 minutes writing up a really instructive answer for him.

Comment: @Jason Ok, and those other errors are what exactly? If I missed something, I'll reopen it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- http://i.imgur.com/vsVJHe8.png

Comment: @Jason Fair enough. I've reopened the question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Excellent, thanks!

Comment: @Jason You're welcome Jason, *cheers*

Comment: @Jason I must note though that we don't know which MySQL API he's using to connect with, so you may want to make a note about that and that they must use the same API from connection to querying.

Comment: Since he phrased his question with "I'm having problems adding...", isn't it safe to assume that he has the proper data from the SQL query on his page already?

Comment: @Jason True, yet we also don't know what's inside `edit.php` so I hope you're not in for a long haul here ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error when you do the button. 
Do something like

```
echo '<input type="button" value="Edit Info">';
```

Replace outer double quotes with single quote.

Comment: or escape the double quotes inside.

Comment: Yes, this is another solution.

Comment: you missed something.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `form` tags from outside of the `while` loop, and try this for the body of the loop:

```
$authorVar = $row['Author'];  
$titleVar = $row['Title'];
$ISBN = $row['ISBN'];

echo "<form method='POST' action='edit.php'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $titleVar. "</td>";   
echo "<td>" . $authorVar. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $ISBN . "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Edit Info'>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='ISBN' value='" . $ISBN . "'>"; 
echo "</form>" ;
```

I fixed the problems with your quotation marks and set up a separate form for each book entry that submits the (unique?) ISBN number using a hidden `input`. You can use this ISBN id to generate your `edit.php` file to match the selected book. Notice I also changed your `input` button from type `button` to type `submit` so that it actually submits the form. Also notice that this button is now inside of `td` tags so that it renders properly.

Comment: thank you very much. this solved my problem and your solution is very easy to understand for someone new to php.